# Include a text area with the same style

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

This is my form[image]

CSS

```
.signin input[type="text"] {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background: #fff url('../images/1.png') no-repeat 345px 10px;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
border: none;
width: 75%;
font-family: Cabin-Regular;
color: gray;
}
.signin  input[type="password"] {
margin-bottom: 20px;
background: #fff url('../images/2.png') no-repeat 345px 10px;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
border: none;
width: 75%;
font-family: Cabin-Regular;
color: gray;
```

html

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Comentanos</h1>
 <div class="contact-form">
 <div class="signin">
 <form>
     <p align="left" style="margin-left:38px; margin-bottom:-5px;"><b>Nombre 
     de Usuario:</b></p>
     <input type="text" class="user" value="Enter Your Username" 
     onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 
     'Enter Your Username';}" />
     <input type="password" class="pass" value="Password" 
     onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 
    'Password';}" />
<!--     <input type="textarea" class="user" value="Enter Your Username" 
    onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 
    'Enter Your Username';}" /> -->
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" cols="95" id="comment">
    </textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="Login" />                  
     <p><a href="#">Lost your password?</a></p>  
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I want a include a textarea. I do this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="7" cols="95" id="comment"></textarea>
```

Result:

[image]

It's a different style! I want a textarea with the same style or similar like this:
[image]

. But the problem is that  I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: That is indeed a standard `<textarea>`. But your `<input>` fields are standard as well. Can you please **clearly** indicate **exactly** how you want the `<texarea>` to appear so that it is the 'same style' as the two `<input>` fields? As it stands, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Okeey! I just do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Solution:

HTML (added class name 'mytextarea'):

```
<textarea class="mytextarea" rows="7" cols="95" id="comment"></textarea>
```

Now your CSS:

```
.mytextarea {

font-size: 16px;
padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
border: none;
font-family: Cabin-Regular;
color: gray;
Width:100%;

}
```

You can also add a `placeholder` to your text area like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="My text area" class="mytextarea" rows="7" cols="95" id="comment"></textarea>
```

As far as i see, you have a border and that is the only difference. Please also note that the `class="form-control"` is from bootstrap and if you want to have your input elements styled in bootstrap, please add bootstrap to your HTML Doc. You can also add attributes to your new text area class and change the looks of it even more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's okey but it have I problem. When you move/change the chrome window size, the textare not chage his size. Then,  the form structure breaks

Comment: @Vidal please see my updated css. Try adding ‘width:100%;’ and check. Also remove the rows and cols and check by adding width. If this helps, please accept my answer.